# Can i have trigger for both 'Before' and 'After' events?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I tried the above scenario by the following piece of code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER test_bf_af2
AFTER LOGON ON SCHEMA and 
BEFORE LOGOFF ON SCHEMA

BEGIN
  --some logic
END;
/
```

but gave me error saying

> Error report: ORA-04079: invalid trigger specification
>
> 4079. 00000 -  "invalid trigger specification"
>
> *Cause:    The create TRIGGER statement is invalid.
>
> *Action:   Check the statement for correct syntax.

So, is it possible to have both types or not? if yes, how can I achieve it?

Comment: You cannot (as far as I know). You need two (2) separate triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a regular DML trigger tt is possible to have multiple events (INSERT, UPDATE) in the same trigger. However, the **timing** must be the same: either BEFORE or AFTER.

It is the same with system triggers. As Oracle supports neither BEFORE LOGON nor AFTER LOGOFF (for obvious reasons) you need two separate triggers.